# Passing ng-click value to one controller and use it in another controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using a table and a button inside the table pops up a modal. I want to pass the Id value in that row to the modal controller so that I can use it to pass it to the the rest api call and then subsequently load valus in the modal table.

App.js

```
var app = angular.module("UiApp", ["ServiceApp"]);

app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var idValue = 'test string value';

    return {
        getId: function () {
            return idValue;
        },
        setId: function (value) {
            idValue = value;
        }
    }
});

app.controller("PortFolioController", function ($scope, GetPortfolios,sharedProperties) {
    $scope.Portfolios = GetPortfolios.query({ pmid: 2 });
    console.log($scope.Portfolios);
    $scope.addOrder = function (id) {
        sharedProperties.setId(id)
    };
});

app.controller("OrderController", function ($scope, GetOrders,sharedProperties) {

    $scope.item = sharedProperties.getId();
    $scope.Orders = GetOrders.query({ id: item});
});
```

Service.js

```
var app = angular.module("ServiceApp", ["ngResource"]);

    app.factory('GetPortfolios', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolios/");
    });

    app.factory('GetOrders', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolioOrders/");
    });
```

HTML

```
<div >
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="editable-sample" ng-controller="PortFolioController">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Portfolio ID</th>
                                                    <th>Portfolio Name</th>
                                                    <th>Portfolio Type</th>
                                                    <th>Portfolio Description</th>
                                                    <th>Show Stocks</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr class="" ng-repeat="portfolio in Portfolios">

                                                    <td>{{portfolio.portfolioId}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{portfolio.portfolioName}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{portfolio.type}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{portfolio.description}}</td>
                                                    <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="addOrder(portfolio.portfolioId)" >Show <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <!--Modal start-->

                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                                        <!-- Modal content-->
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">My Portfolio</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <h3>Stock List</h3>
                                                <div class="space15"></div>
                                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="editable-sample" ng-controller="OrderController">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Symbol</th>
                                                            <th>Stock Name</th>
                                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                                            <th>Market Price</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr class="" ng-repeat="order in Orders">
                                                            <td>{{order.symbol}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{order.executedQuantity}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{order.price}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{order.createTStamp}}</td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                            </div>
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @manish it shows the item value is not defined.

Comment: Are you using [UIBootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?  If so, then you are looking for the [resolve] option (just look for it on that page-- they don't make it easy to link directly).

Comment: No I have put just a part of html code, Everything is present

Comment: what display `console.log($scope.Portfolios);`?

Answer (score 1):

In PortFolioController Controller, you can do:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', id);
```

and listen to the event in OrderController Controller:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, id) {...});
```

Also you can use [AngularJS Service Passing Data Between Controllers to see some examples](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

or the simpleset way without any `service` is to use `$rootScope` and `$broadcast` an `event` from one `Controller` and listen to it in the other `Controller`

thus, No need of writing an extra service `sharedProperties`

Something like this :-

```
app.controller("PortFolioController", function ($scope, GetPortfolios,$rootScope) {
   //Other Codes
   $scope.addOrder = function (id) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('ID-Clicked', { Id: id});
   };
}

app.controller("OrderController", function ($scope, GetOrders,$rootScope) {
    //Other Codes
    //Listen for the event
    $rootScope.$on('ID-Clicked', function(event, data){
      $scope.item = data.Id;// data.Id has the Clicked Id
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to pass GetPortfolios in OrderController?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, i was copying my initial code and forgot to get rid of that service, edited my answer

Comment: Debug time, could you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

This approach can be done using 2 ways.

First Way is to broadcast some events from the parent rootscope instance and capture that on the $scope elements.This format is not considered as a good way of coding.

Secondly, to communicate data between controllers use a service.Yeah you are currently on the right,clean & widely accepted path.

Remember that services are singletons.so once instansiated it is available to all controllers.But the challenge here is as soon as you click on button element your service sets your `idValue` in the service.Now how does the second controller know that.The answer would be register a $watch service to watch if the idValue in the service is changed as below.

```
  app.controller("OrderController", function ($scope, GetOrders, sharedProperties) {
              $scope.$watch(function () {
                  return sharedProperties.getId()
              }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                  if (newValue != oldValue) {
                      $scope.item = newValue;
                      $scope.Orders = GetOrders.query({ id: item });
                  }
              });

          });
```